# 4 digit regex which maybe starts with 0

Tags: regex, digits

```
\b(0?[1-9]){4}
```

I have this Regex
Which can find

```
1234
```

But not

```
0123
```

It finds 01234 which is more than 4 digits

Which part of my Regex is wrong?

Comment: Do you *want* `1234` to match? (if so, why not just `\d{4}`?)

Comment: FYI: You could give https://regexr.com/ a try.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes

Comment: So why not just `\d{4}`?

Comment: @WillBickford it's a good site, but does not support multiline regex, i think

Comment: @CertainPerformance this is a part of bigger Regex which can be {1-2-3-4} digit number which can be start with zero so \d is not a good idea if you have a solution for that it could helps

Comment: you want 4 digits, and the first digit and he other 3 digits can be zero? or must the other 3 digits be non-zero? (a *good* specification must be *very* specific - and programs/computer require that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that you've specified `?` for the 0 match, which means zero or one matches. Thus, you can match 5-digit strings (and larger ones) as a result.

The problem is that `?` contributes 0 or 1 and then your `1-9` test always contributes 1. You do a match 4 times, so you could match anything from a 4-digit to an 8-digit string.

Here's a much simpler version, which you can test with https://regexr.com/.

```
\b[0-9][1-9]{3}\b
```

This tests for 0-9 in the first position, and then 1-9 in the next 3, just as required.

### Example Output

```
yes: 1234
yes: 0123
no:  01234
no:  12345
no:  0001
yes: 0125
```

Comment: ty for simple solution

Comment: This is obviously better than my approach - dunno why I was so focussed on the alternation.. I will however keep my answer in place in case intermediate `0`s are allowed.

Comment: "`1-9` test always contributes 4" is incorrect.  `0104079` and `140208` and `09080706` match as well.  Solution is correct and straightforward though.

Answer (score 3):

Your quantifier is used for the whole group, thus you could also match `01020304` with your current regex.

The most simple solution seems to be an alternation in this case:

```
\b(?:0[1-9]{3}|[1-9]{4})\b
```

Note that this will not match numbers that have the `0` inside, like `3000`.

If however you just wanted to make sure, not to match `0000`, you could use a lookahead instead

```
\b(?!0{4})\d{4}\b
```